# how to select a range of list items with html

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, testng, html-lists

I have a list in my application. The list is seperated into sections such as "currently viewing as", "recently viewed" and "staff" etc.  All list elements share the same classes so it isn't straight forward to identify the list element in the section recently viewed for instance.

I tried the following:

```
RecentlyViewed(".list-group-item:nth-of-type(3)"
        .concat("~ .list-group-item:nth-of-type(4)"))
```

but that seems to only return 1 list item and not both of them.

Any pointers in returning both the 3rd item and the 4th item in the list?.

Incidently the above locator is passed to a method like the following :

```
private WebElement sectionSearch(String locator, String empName) {
    return wait.andGetAllElements(locator).stream()
        .filter(ele -> ele.getAttribute("data-empno").equals(empName))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not find employee: ".concat(empName)
          .concat(" in element : ").concat(locator)));
  }
```

Any ideas where i may be going wrong on the list items being passed to the search function?

The html is as follows:

```
<div id="context-selector-search-results" class="list-group list-group-menu"><h4 class="text-muted">You are signed in as...</h4><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">

            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="3000" data-url="api/context/select/3000"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="file/photo/T000~|~3000~|~2915483350193499~|~GIF~|~1~|~ok.gif" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">3000</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">MANAGER3000, Mary G</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><h4 class="text-muted">Currently viewing...</h4><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split active active-warning">

            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="5029" data-url="api/context/select/5029"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="assets/ui/img/avatar.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">5029</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">EMPLOYEE, Earl</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><h4 class="text-muted">Recently viewed...</h4><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">

            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="5029" data-url="api/context/select/5029"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="assets/ui/img/avatar.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">5029</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">EMPLOYEE, Earl</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">

            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="5027" data-url="api/context/select/5027"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="assets/ui/img/avatar.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">5027</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">EMPLOYEE, Earlene</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><h4 class="text-muted">My staff</h4><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-more" data-display-name="JETSON, Jane" data-expand-id="E~4112016">
          <span class="tag tag-pill tag-primary hidden-xs-down float-xs-right">20</span>
        </a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="4112016" data-url="api/context/select/4112016"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="file/photo/T000~|~4112016~|~2915756609048099~|~PNG~|~1~|~janejetson.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">4112016</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">JETSON, Jane</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-more" data-display-name="PERSON130218, Eric" data-expand-id="E~130218">
          <span class="tag tag-pill tag-primary hidden-xs-down float-xs-right">20</span>
        </a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="130218" data-url="api/context/select/130218"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="assets/ui/img/avatar.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">130218</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">PERSON130218, Eric</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-more" data-display-name="ROBOTS, Eric" data-expand-id="E~3001">
          <span class="tag tag-pill tag-primary hidden-xs-down float-xs-right">20</span>
        </a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="3001" data-url="api/context/select/3001"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="assets/ui/img/avatar.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">3001</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">ROBOTS, Eric</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-more" data-display-name="SNODGRASS, Harold" data-expand-id="E~3003">
          <span class="tag tag-pill tag-primary hidden-xs-down float-xs-right">20</span>
        </a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="3003" data-url="api/context/select/3003"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="assets/ui/img/avatar.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">3003</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">SNODGRASS, Harold</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-more" data-display-name="SNODGRASS, Harold" data-expand-id="E~3004">
          <span class="tag tag-pill tag-primary hidden-xs-down float-xs-right">20</span>
        </a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="3004" data-url="api/context/select/3004"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="assets/ui/img/avatar.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">3004</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">SNODGRASS, Harold</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-more" data-display-name="VON DA EMPLOYEE, Eric" data-expand-id="E~5031">
          <span class="tag tag-pill tag-primary hidden-xs-down float-xs-right">20</span>
        </a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="5031" data-url="api/context/select/5031"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="file/photo/T000~|~2031~|~2915405557111499~|~JPEG~|~1~|~0A1BE6FA-43C4-4E85-A110-9F797A9525E6.jpeg" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">5031</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">VON DA EMPLOYEE, Eric</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-split">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-more" data-display-name="WAYNE, Bruce" data-expand-id="E~80000">
          <span class="tag tag-pill tag-primary hidden-xs-down float-xs-right">20</span>
        </a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item-link" data-empno="80000" data-url="api/context/select/80000"><div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="context-selector-search-results-item-image media-object rounded-circle img-avatar" alt="Avatar" src="file/photo/T000~|~80000~|~2915797423381199~|~JPG~|~1~|~bruce-wayne_197x282.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-empno">80000</small>
            <br>
            <strong class="context-selector-search-results-item-display-name">WAYNE, Bruce</strong>
            <br>

            <small class="context-selector-search-results-item-unit">Manufacturing Division</small><br>

          </div>
        </div></a>
        </li></div>
```

Comment: you should implement something like [custom-component](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/custom_component.html)

Comment: @user861594 How does that solve the problem?

Comment: Refer [property example](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/custom_component.html) in that example, it helps take list of properties and you can work required one, for example getting rate, rate options etc. Same way here creating component for `employee` can help working with list of employees and accessing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is by using XPath. If you pass in your empno to a function and then insert that into the XPath below, it will return the first h4 preceding the found element. You can then match that with what you are expecting, etc.

```
//a[@data-empno='4112016']/preceding::h4
```

This returns 'My staff'

You would insert your variable like

```
"//a[@data-empno='"+ empno + "']/preceding::h4"
```

Comment: Hi @JeffC I resolved my problem with the following expression(but your example helped a lot:  //h4[contains(text(),'My staff')]/following::a[@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-em')][last()]]

Comment: I am runnig into difficulties with identifying the recently viewed elements which lie between 2 h4 elements.  I tired the following but it doesnt work:  //h4[contains(text(),'Recently viewed...')]/[following::a[@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-em')][last()]] and preceding::h4[contains(text(), 'My staff')]]   any ideas on that?

Comment: That's a different question. You should post a new question with all the details of what you've tried and the relevant HTML.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: Sorry @JeffC i cant uptick you yet being a newbie to the site and all.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my issue using the following xpath:

```
//h4[contains(text(),'My staff')]/following::a[@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-em')]
```